# MobileFirst hybrid app for iOS doesn't work after icloud restore

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, backup, icloud, restore

I've bought a new iPhone and I've initialized it from an iCloud backup of my former iPhone. Moreover I have an hybrid iOS app developed with MobileFirst 7.1. After the restore to the new iPhone, I tried to run that app but unfortunately I got this error message:

```
[FATAL] [WL_INIT] +[HybridSecurityUtils testWebResourcesChecksum] in HybridSecurityUtils.m:101 :: Web resources integrity test: Failure. Reinstall the application and try again.
```

In the hybrid app there was the security "checksum of web resources" feature active: but I don't understand whether the backup/restore changed somehow the web resources making the checksum fails; or some web resources haven't been included in the backup/restore for any reason.

Do Anybody experienced the same issue ?

Comment: Was the app updated either via play store or through a direct update ?

Comment: The app is updated by iTunes Connect. We’ve deactivated Direct Uodate.

Comment: So, my question essentially is whether the version of the app installed prior to restore and after the restore the same or different ?

Comment: what is the iOS version on your new phone and what was the iOS version on your old phone?

Comment: The app version is the same. Ios version is iOS 11.1.2 for both.